# Rails redirect_to is broken over SSL on Nginx/Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ssl, nginx, unicorn

I have a simple Rails controller that takes a URL as a query param and responds with a redirect to that URL.

```
def redirectme
  if params[:url]
    redirect_to params[:url]
  else
    render json: nil, status: 404
  end
end
```

When I deploy this code to my production stack (Nginx/Unicorn), the controller works as expected when invoked over `http` -- i.e. it does the redirection and you get the response of the `params[:url]` page. But when invoked over `https`, I get the dreaded response: `<html><body>You are being <a href="[URL]">redirected</a>.</body></html>`.

I've researched this problem, and most folks seem to have fixed it by setting the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. I already had this set in my conf file, so I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong. The rest of my app works just fine.

Here is a subset of my two server blocks:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

server {
  listen   443;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-CLIENT-VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing Rails to serve up the "You are being redirected" page instead of actually executing the redirection?